# How to solve this odd error in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I upgraded mysql 5.5 to 5.6 in directadmin
and now http://p30rank.ir/phpmyadmin/
has error

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
```

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

But http://p30rank.ir/phpMyAdmin

open without error

why?

Comment: works both on my side, at least until the login.

Answer (score 1):

Because the directory where this is stored is called `phpMyAdmin` and not `phpmyadmin` and somehow an alias got lost or `mod_speling` got turned off or whatever. That's what you get when using crappy admin frontends - they do something and you don't know what and are in trouble if something goes wrong.